# Search data between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the data between two dates and I wrote the query as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM hospital_details 
WHERE expirydate BETWEEN '03/13/2015' AND '03/18/2015'
```

But it also displays the results of `03/17/2016`

How can I solve it?

Comment: What's $Date and $b?

Comment: and what format/datatype is your expierydate column?

Comment: You can use the where function twice with the query builder class. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data or http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: Dates adhere to a specific format in sql. This is not it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write single syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM hospital_details WHERE ExpiryDate BETWEEN '$Date' AND '$b';
```

Answer (score 0):

The active record where function will take an associative array;

```
$array = array('expirydate >= ' => $Date, 'expirydate <= ' => $b);
$this->db->where($array);
```

or a custome string;

```
$where = "expirydate > ='$Date' AND expirydate < ='$b'";
$this->db->where($where);
```

Obviously, make sure your variables are in the right format.
[Active record docs here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)